# cakePHP multiple model

Tags: cakephp, model

Hi i've been using cakephp for 1 month and i have found this code in a webapp that i'm fixing.

```
$availableParts = $this->Line->Part->getAvailablePartsForLineWithComponentType($id, $componentType['ComponentType']['id'], $selectedParts);
```

Line and Part are two models, and i don't understand why Line is mentioned to call a method of Part model.

Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say where this code is being called from, but from it's format I'm going to assume it is within an action of the `lines_controller.php`.

If my assumptions are correct, then the reason for calling a method on the `Part` model via the `Line` model is that the `Line` model will be automatically available in the lines controller, and using this method of getting to the `Part` model saves writing code to manually load the `Part` model.

It's a convenience, promotes consistency in your controllers, and should also save memory in cases where that line of code isn't called and the associated model doesn't need to be loaded (lazy loading).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the context of the code it's impossible to tell. So provide more information and code.

But technically it's ok to call another model through the association. So for your understanding: It's ok to do that. But why exactly it is done in the case is a question for the former programmer of this code.

Comment: Sorry for not speciefying the context. That piece of code is in the Line Controller, i thought it was enough do something like this:

    $availableParts = $this->Part->getAvailablePartsForLineWithComponentType($id, $componentType['ComponentType']['id'], $selectedParts);